# $\dim N_1 X$ and $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $\mathbb{F}_n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $X$ is a smooth projective rational surface such that $-K_X$ is big, then why is it that if $\dim N_1X \leq 2$, then $X \cong \mathbb{P}^2$ or $X \cong \mathbb{F}_n$, a Hirzebruch surface.

I would appreciate any justification or even some direction to the literature. Thanks.

Comment: When you write \text{dim} N rather than \dim N, then you don't get automatic proper spacing before and after $\dim$, so you see $\text{dim} N$ rather than $\dim N$.  One can tell what you did before seeing the code.  I changed it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I am not sure I understand the role of the hypothesis "$-K_X$ is big". Do you know the classification of minimal rational surfaces?

Comment: Google "minimal rational surface".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is direct by Minimal Model Program on smooth surfaces.

Since $-K_X$ is big, after running MMP, $X$ ends up with a Mori fiber space, which is $\mathbb{P}^2$ or $\mathbb{F}_n$ with $n\neq 1$.

On the other hand, if $X$ is not a Mori fiber space, then by the Picard number assumption, $X$ can only be $\mathbb{P}^2$ blowing up one point, which is $\mathbb{F}_1$.

Comment: +1. Note that (as I commented above) the assumption "$-K_X$ is big" is unnecessary if we know that $X$ is rational.